# Split number in groups based on other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one challenge with some query I have to build and I am a little bit lost on how to start. I guess I may need to use partition by to achieve this but not sure on they way.
So posting here if someone can share the knowledge with me :)

First of all sorry for the confusing tittle but honestly didn't know how to describe it with a single line :(

The thing is that I have two tables:

**INVENTORY**

```
ITEM    QTY    PRIORITY
-----------------------------
ITEM1   10     1
ITEM1   5      2
ITEM1   4      3
ITEM1   7      4
ITEM2   4      1
ITEM2   19     2
```

**LIST**

```
ITEM       QTY
-----------------
ITEM1      17
ITEM2      13
```

The logic I need to achieve is that the table LIST removes the quantities from the INVENTORY table. But it has to do it by item and removing the quantities in priority level.
For example:

In LIST table we have ITEM1 = 17
This means that we need to remove this quantities in Inventory table by following the priority order.

1. First removing from first priority (qty =10 - 10 --> We still have 7 from LIST table)
2. Then removing  from second priority (qty = 5 - 5 --> We still have 2 from LIST table)
3. Then removing from third priority  (qty = 4 - 2!!! --> We were only having 2 left from LIST table)

So result for ITEM1 would be like:

```
ITEM    QTY    PRIORITY
-----------------------------
ITEM1   0      1
ITEM1   0      2
ITEM1   2      3
ITEM1   7      4
```

If applying the whole logic to all the items then the resulting query should return something like:

```
ITEM    QTY    PRIORITY
-----------------------------
ITEM1   0      1
ITEM1   0      2
ITEM1   2      3
ITEM1   7      4
ITEM2   0      1
ITEM2   10     2
```

Anyone having some idea on how could I approach this?

Comment: Are there only 4 different levels of Priority or does that change?

Comment: It changes... The idea was to use sorting and take start from the first one. Also noone assures that they will be sequential (can be 1,7,11,15,...)

Comment: Thank you **SO MUCH** for providing all the sample input and expected output details, along with your logic; so nice not to have to try and guess what the question is about! *{:-D

Comment: :) Welcome. I know how is to work with minimal info and is not reccomended, so thats why I dropped all I could. Thanks to you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE inventory ( item, qty, priority ) AS
SELECT 'ITEM1', 10, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM1',  5, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM1',  4, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM1',  7, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM2',  4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM2', 19, 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE list ( item, qty ) AS
SELECT 'ITEM1', 17 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM2', 13 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
MERGE INTO inventory dst
USING (
  SELECT i.item,
         LEAST(
           GREATEST(
             SUM( i.qty ) OVER ( PARTITION BY i.item ORDER BY i.priority )
               - COALESCE( l.qty, 0 ),
             0
           ),
           i.qty
         ) AS qty,
         i.priority
  FROM   inventory i
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         list l
         ON ( i.item = l.item )
) src
ON ( src.item = dst.item AND src.priority = dst.priority )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET qty = src.qty;
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory;

ITEM  QTY PRIORITY
----- --- --------
ITEM1   0        1
ITEM1   0        2
ITEM1   2        3
ITEM1   7        4
ITEM2   0        1
ITEM2  10        2
```

Comment: what happen if you add for the item1 the qty 19 with priority 5 ?

Comment: @Nemeros If you try it then you will see that it does not change that row - just like it does not change the row with `item = ITEM1` and `priority = 4` (as per the OP's expected output).

Comment: @MT0 Fabulous answer! Truly, your brain is very twisty *{:-D

Comment: Thanks MT0! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was able to adapt it to my scenario (this was more a basic approach) and it worked perfectly :) And I have to say that I agree with Boneist, this is only comming from a twisty brain ;)  Thanks a ton for this great approach!

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with the judicious use of analytic functions to calculate a running sum, and to get the amount left over to be deleted from the previous row, like so:

```
WITH inventory AS (SELECT 'ITEM1' item, 10 qty, 1 priority FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'ITEM1' item, 5 qty, 2 priority FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'ITEM1' item, 4 qty, 3 priority FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'ITEM1' item, 7 qty, 4 priority FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'ITEM2' item, 4 qty, 1 priority FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'ITEM2' item, 19 qty, 2 priority FROM dual),
          LIST AS (SELECT 'ITEM1' item, 17 qty FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'ITEM2' item, 13 qty FROM dual),
-- end of mimicking your two tables; you would not need to do the above
-- see below for the main query
   interim_res AS (SELECT inv.item,
                          inv.qty,
                          inv.priority,
                          l.qty qty_to_del,
                          l.qty - SUM(inv.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY inv.item ORDER BY inv.priority) qty_left_to_del
                   FROM   inventory inv
                          INNER JOIN LIST l ON inv.item = l.item),
     final_res AS (SELECT item,
                          qty,
                          priority,
                          qty_to_del,
                          qty_left_to_del,
                          LAG(qty_left_to_del, 1, qty_to_del) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY priority) qty_to_del_from_current_qty
                   FROM   interim_res)
SELECT item,
       qty old_qty,
       CASE WHEN qty_to_del_from_current_qty >= qty 
                 THEN 0
            WHEN qty_to_del_from_current_qty > 0
                 THEN qty - qty_to_del_from_current_qty
            ELSE qty
       END new_qty,
       priority
FROM   final_res;

ITEM     OLD_QTY    NEW_QTY   PRIORITY
----- ---------- ---------- ----------
ITEM1         10          0          1
ITEM1          5          0          2
ITEM1          4          2          3
ITEM1          7          7          4
ITEM2          4          0          1
ITEM2         19         10          2
```

In order to solve your problem, first off I created a running sum of the qty in the inventory table, across each item and in the priority order. We can then use that to delete from the qty in the items table, to find out how much we have left over to delete from the next qty (ignore the fact that we can get negative values as part of this).

Once we have that, next we need to associate the qty left to be deleted from the previous row - we use LAG() to do that - and for the first row, we default it to be the full items.qty (that's what the third parameter is about).

(N.B. I put this calculation in a separate subquery simply so that we don't have to repeat the LAG() function all over the place; we can refer to it as the column alias in the final outer query. You could combine the final_res subquery and the outer query into one, if you don't mind having all the LAG()s!)

Once we know the value to delete from our items.qty, we know we have one of three actions to take:

1. The full qty is deleted - ie. qty_to_delete >= items.qty. This will result in a qty of 0
2. Part of the qty is deleted - ie. we have a non-negative qty_to_delete which is less than the items.qty. We can simply do items.qty - qty_to_delete in this case.
3. Finally, we have a 0 or negative amount to delete, which is an invalid state in our scenario, so we don't need to delete anything from the items.qty.

Finally, to update your table, I would use MERGE. Assuming that in the inventory table, (item, priority) is a unique key, the following ought to work:

```
MERGE INTO items tgt
  USING (WITH interim_res AS (SELECT inv.item,
                                     inv.qty,
                                     inv.priority,
                                     l.qty qty_to_del,
                                     l.qty - SUM(inv.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY inv.item ORDER BY inv.priority) qty_left_to_del
                              FROM   inventory inv
                                     INNER JOIN LIST l ON inv.item = l.item),
                final_res AS (SELECT item,
                                     qty,
                                     priority,
                                     qty_to_del,
                                     qty_left_to_del,
                                     LAG(qty_left_to_del, 1, qty_to_del) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY priority) qty_to_del_from_current_qty
                              FROM   interim_res)
         SELECT item,
                qty old_qty,
                CASE WHEN qty_to_del_from_current_qty >= qty 
                          THEN 0
                     WHEN qty_to_del_from_current_qty > 0
                          THEN qty - qty_to_del_from_current_qty
                     ELSE qty
                END new_qty,
                priority
         FROM   final_res) src
ON (tgt.item = src.item AND tgt.priority = src.priority)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.qty = src.new_qty
  WHERE tgt.qty != src.new_qty;
```

Comment: Thanks Boneist! Nice approach! I used the other solution proposed by MT0 but I really think it is interesting to see different approaches to learn about the power of Oracle (specially with the partitions). Thanks again!!

Comment: MT0's solution is better by far than mine! *{:-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in oracle but looks like you need cumulative sum (running total). See [here](http://nimishgarg.blogspot.com.by/2010/02/oracle-getting-cumulative-sum-using.html) or [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:305416600201)

```
SELECT item, 
       priority,
       qty,
       SUM(qty) OVER 
              (ORDER BY priority RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) c_qty
FROM inventory
```

Let's mark the query as `sub`

Then you can use

```
select
  list.*
  case when sub.c_qty<list.qty then 0 else list.qty-sub.c_qty
from list
     inner join sub on list.item=sub.item
```

Comment: Hi Stanislav, thanks for your reply! I finally used another approach (see above). I tried your query but unfortunatelly i didnt got the expected result. But still I will see what can be done with the RANGE you mention in the OVER clause. Thanks!!